# Duplicate content - linking to other versions of same page

Tags: seo, google, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two URLs pointing to almost the same content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14284/two-urls-pointing-to-almost-the-same-content)

If I have a page, that has this URL:

- `example.com/category/something/`

but can also be accessed through these URLs:

- `example.com/category/something/1`
- `example.com/category/something/2`
- `example.com/category/something/3`

where the last number is used as an image-index to display a certain image on the page. So the content of the pages is the same, just with one image changed.

How do I avoid google indexing the versions with `/number` at the end, so it only shows up once in searches - and is not considered duplicate content?

Is it enough to put a `rel="nofollow"` on links to the `/number` links?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a **canonical tag** that points to:

- `example.com/category/something`

So that Google looks at the other URLs you mentioned, it definitely knows that they belong to the main-page defined in the canonical tag. [Here is the official Google blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) and the explanation for the canonical URL. By the way, putting a rel nofollow would be unnecessary dangerous since they are somehow counted too and may have a negative impact on your SEO.

Comment: Thank you :) I really felt that my work was ignored when John Conde closed the post, but now i feel honored! Thank you:)

Comment: Yeah, I know -- it's why I said hi... :-) ...if you post the answer to the question John linked to, I'll upvote your answer there too. Cheers!